# ASP .NET Reques.Form DropDownlist strange behavior

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have an issue getting the selected value of a dropdownlist.

My view source looks like this:

```
<div class="editor-field">  
  <select class="list" id="DivisionesLists" name="DivisionesLists">
    <option value=""> -- Seleccione -- </option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">COORPORATIVO</option>
    <option value="2">MANUFACTURA</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
string s = Request.Form["DivisionesLists"];
```

The problem is that Request.Form["DivisionesLists"] returns "1,1" instead of just "1" (which is the actual selected value of the dropdownlist).

What may be happening?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using an ASP.Net DropDownList control?  It would probably make life simpler...

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use a server control like ListBox? This is just html. Anyway, probably you have another select list with the same ID. Visual Studio would tell you about that.

Comment: Do you have any other field on the page with the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might also be posting some additional data, what happens if you select the first one, what does it post back?  Does it post anything back with a comma?

It could be a duplicate control... though like Html.CheckBox action method: it renders the checkbox control and a hidden field that represents the value when the checkbox isn't there; accessing the value when its checked is true,false.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

If the select isn't a multiple select I think you have another control (input or select) that have the same name attribute on the page.

Comment: No, I already searched for that in the page source and it's the only control with that ID and Name.

Comment: Do you have any javascript that changes the values of the select before posting?

Comment: If you have anything rendered client-side "show source" may not show it, e.g. something rendered dynamically in an UpdatePanel. Try looking at the page with a debugging tool in firefox or chrome. But then I assume your client-side IDs would not be so simple...